What does to run a gun mean?
I came across this polysemic phrase "On 29 April 1862 Flag Officer David Farragut had run the guns of Fort Jackson and Fort St Philip to seize control of New Orleans".
Ferguson, Niall. The Ascent of Money: A Financial History of the World: 10th Anniversary Edition (English Edition) (p. 86). Penguin Publishing Group. Edición de Kindle.
After looking up the multiple meanings of "run" as a verb in Webster's Third New International Dictionary Unabridged, I came to the conclusion that the intended meaning is to say that Mr. Farragut fired too many shots from his guns to the point that he almost ran out of bullets, that he was the one operating the guns in those battles but I am not sure though. There is another meaning related to "smuggle" but I do not think this is the case.

Please give us the source of your quote.

@RonaldSole I think that would be Niall Ferguson the author of The Ascent of Money, I did include the bibliographic citation.

Have you tried the Wikipedia page on Farragut which describes the incident in some detail, even using the word "run" in the sentence "After two days of heavy bombardment, Farragut ran past forts Jackson and St. Philip and the Chalmette batteries to take the city and port of New Orleans on April 29, a decisive event in the war."?

It couldn't mean "fired too many shots", because that phrase is "ran out".  You never see just ran by itself to mean "ran out".

@Quique +1.  It's a good question for ELL.. It helps to understand how the meaning of a phrase is often unrelated to the meanings of the individual words. Why did someone downvote? +1

There is no reason at all to dv this question. Also, the right answer has been provided by James, in this case.

A flag officer is a senior officer in a navy. To run an obstacle or hazard (e.g. a blockade, some guns, a weir or waterfall, 'the gauntlet'), possibly in a ship, boat, vehicle or aircraft, is to move past or through it. In a car one can run (wrongly pass) a red traffic light or stop sign. In a kayak or canoe you can run a waterfall, weir, or rapids in a river.

Run verb (transitive)
3 (c)
: to slip or go through or past
run a blockade
run a red light

Run (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)

+1.   And run the gauntlet.

@TimR - Deliberately going over a weir or waterfall in a river, in a boat, is called running it.

@TimR - one can run a risk.

This does not really get the point. To run the guns of the fort: evade fire from the guns in the fort and make it to the port.

OP's query is on the meaning of the phrase,  "had run the guns of":

I came across this polysemic phrase
"On 29 April 1862 Flag Officer David Farragut had run the guns of Fort Jackson and Fort St Philip to seize control of New Orleans".
I came to the conclusion that the intended meaning is to say that Mr. Farragut fired too many shots from his guns

The following is a paragraph from the article titled,  "Capture of New Orleans".

Despite taking heavy fire from the Confederate forts and a melee with defending Confederate vessels, Farragut shattered Confederate resistance.
At one point, a Confederate fire raft collided with Hartford, resulting in “flames bursting through the ports and running up the rigging, endangering the ship much from fire.”3 Ordered to fire stations,
the crew quelled the flames and continued to return fire.
Confederate losses in this engagement ran to more than a dozen vessels, while Farragut suffered the loss of only one ship, Varuna.
Flag-Officer David G. Farragut and the Capture of New Orleans

This account clearly shows how Farragut maneuvered his fleet while facing heavy fire, continuing to advance despite the Confederate forts' guns.
Therefore, "to run the guns of" means to advance through or confront intense gunfire to breach a defensive line.
In this historical context, it represents Farragut’s fleet enduring and withstanding intense fire as they navigated past the forts.
Edit-1.
Run the guns - U.S. Civil War

Forcing naval passage under cannon fire
Envision a fort, overlooking a river, with artillery. To get past it, one takes your naval forces and "run the guns", as you are literally trying to sail as quickly past the guns as possible to hopefully avoid getting hit..
.
The U.S. Civil War


This is the right answer. The other one is mistaken.

In this case it means that he went through enemy fire to take the city. The named forts were firing on him and his unit (not sure if this is foot or naval, I suspect the latter but it is not clear from the short quote). In this case "run" is used to convey that troops in such a position are usually in a great hurry.

Plenty of sources state that Farragut was in charge of a fleet of ships, the West Gulf Blockading Squadron, with instructions to enter the Mississippi and capture New Orleans. He was in command of eighteen wooden vessels including his flagship Hartford, a fleet of mortar boats, and 700 men.  'Run' here has nothing to do with being in a hurry. One can run a blockade or barrage slowly or carefully.

I was going strictly by the quote and did not bother looking for actual history. It would have the same meaning even if it came from fiction.

@SoronelHaetir Though you say you went strictly by the the quote, you got the meaning right - In this case it means that he went through enemy fire to take the city. The named forts were firing on him and his unit

This is also correct.
